# Unable to download file using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my down loader controller. First time it works properly. it opens save as popup and able to download required file, But next time it shows direct directory listing.

[image]

```
<?php

class Download extends Controller {

 function Download(){
  parent::Controller();
  $this->load->helper('download');
  echo "I am in constructor";

 }

 function index(){
  $file = realpath("download")."\\profile.doc"; 
  echo "I am in index.";

        exit;

  if (file_exists($file)) {
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }else{

   // File Not Found

         echo "File not found";
        }

 }
}
?>
```

Comment: How does your URL change between "first" and "second" try?

Comment: It might be useful to know that CodeIgniter has it's own download helper, for exactly your requirement - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html

Comment: what do you mean by next time? after clicking the download link from the same page again?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the download helper as seen in the [user_guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html). It deals with this type of situation.